# Почему "схлопывается" width при position: absolute?

Tags: html, css

Вот пример: http://jsfiddle.net/alpha9000/Wddfs/

```css
p {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
article {
  background: #222;
  width: 60%;
}
.cb {
  clear: both;
}
article div {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.left,
.middle,
.right {
  float: left;
  height: 200px;
}
.left {
  background: #aaa;
  width: 20%;
}
.right {
  background: #aaa;
  width: 20%;
}
.middle {
  position: relative;
  background: #ccc;
  width: 60%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.middle p {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 80%;
  padding: 5px 0px;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="middle">
    <p>hello
      <br/>moto</p>
  </div>
  <div class="right"></div>
  <div class="cb"></div>
</article>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему у

схлопывается width(по логике вещей

должен быть во всю длинну .middle)?
Корректно ли решать так: width: 100%?

Comment: товарищи, сделайте комментарий ответом чтобы я мог принять правильный

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы ж задали элементу **position: absolute;**. В этом случае, надо явно указывать параметры высоты и ширины, даже если элемент блочный. Допишите **width: 100%;** и [всё нормализуется](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/Wddfs/1/).

Answer (score 4):

Интересная штука тут получается. Это происходит из-за того, что абсолютно позиционированный элемент выпадает из привычного течения. Они получают width и height 0, и браузер заново подсчитывает размер (высоту и ширину) этого элемента в соответствии с его содержимым, а не наследует от отцовского элемента как это происходит обычно. Поэтому, нужно указывать ширину и высоту при необходимости.